# Streiten vs sich streiten

Tags: translation, difference

Was genau ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden? Die beiden werden meistenteils als entweder "to argue" oder "to quarrel" übersetzt. Kann "to fight over something" eine der Möglichkeiten sein? Wenn es in Verbindung mit "über" benutzt wird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beide Begriffe bedeuten das Gleiche. Ich denke, dass 'sich streiten' eher umgangssprachlich benutzt wird und 'streiten' eher formal ist.